# Is it true that google will punish a pre-render service for search engine if my website developed in SPA?

Tags: seo, single-page-application

I've told many times that "you should never develop your website in SPA if you want SEO available".

Someone told me that, if your SPA returns an empty `index.html` to end-user as following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>demo</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="startup.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

And you use a pre-render service for search engine, that the crawler will retrieve the full rendered html content. Which means the html content that end-user get and crawler get are different.

If we do in this way, my website will be punished by google.

Can someone give me an official documentation about this?

Comment: You need help of some site providing legal advise. I'm vote this question as off-topic because the site doesn't entertain questions for legal advice but programming only. Take a look at the tour and the help center to get a better understanding of how this site works, expecially the on-topic section.

Comment: I don't think it's a legal issue. I am asking for the detail specification of SEO for single-page-application. So please don't close my topic, maybe someone else can help me find the specification. ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not cloaking, we (Google) wouldn't penalise for that.

Please take a look at the [Ajax Crawling Scheme](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/174992), which essentially describes the same thing, except it works on different URLs.

[image]

You can do this on any URL. One thing to keep in mind though, is that most big search engines, [including Google](http://www.googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.il/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html), already renders the pages just like a normal browser would, so perhaps you don't even need to create the HTML snapshot.

Comment: Would Google give a higher ranking to non-SPA websites? Loading the content via Ajax will inevitably slow down the crawling process, because after the initial HTML output the bot has to wait for the content to update and find any <a> tag to follow.